# Plot chart from datagridview Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, charts, datagridview

So this is my code I have for datagridview

```
 Me.tblRecord.Rows.Add(txtCurBat.Text, answer, txtCurAvDam.Text)
```

x-axis = txtCurBat
y-axis = txtCurAvDam

Please help, I will be very thankful... I've done a lot of research and can't get it right.

Kind regards.

PS while user uses the program, rows in datagridview increase, so the graph should propagate as well.

Comment: This is not a good question I'm afraid. It basically reads "I have a grid, show me how to graph its contents". That's just too broad for SO. This is not a place to be taught the basics or have your code written for you. There are plenty of places that you can learn how to graph data and once you know that, you simply need to work out how to extract the data from the grid into a form the chart can use. Stop thinking that it's just one task. It's two completely separate tasks so treat them that way, research them that way and learn them that way. Post back when you encounter an actual issue.

Comment: No problem! I understand =)